# Offsetting a value in dict() by an user input numerical value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a Ceaser Cipher as a beginner project to force myself in the deep end and learn Python. I am trying to create the program entirely on the knowledge I have built up and seeking external advice to just grasp the syntax and application methods better.

## Problem:

For a small snippet of code I am trying to get a dict() for a-z = 0-25 that can then be offset by a user input value.

So if the user inputs 2, then it would be a-z = 2-27.

I havent worked out the looping logic for this yet so that the max value never goes past 25, but resets to 0 and loops. But I will get there in due time.

## Code

What my code currently looks like:

```
values = dict()
for index, letter in enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase):
    values[letter] = index + 0
```

## Expected

What I want to add:

```
values_offset = values + int(input("What is the offset you'd like to add?"))
print (values_offset['a'])
```

I would like the 2nd code block above to then know/print that if the user input is '2', for example as the offset, that 'a' will then return as '2' instead of '0'.

## Error

Currenly I am getting a error for the types not being able to just be added together.

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'int'
```

So this is where my issues currently lies. I do not know what I can do to make the offset get simply added to the indexed value that is assigned to 'a'.

I am assuming this kind of logic is not as simple as 'dict()' is a technical library of letters in this case and cant just be added simply str or int which is 1 thing.

Comment: `values[letter] = index + 0` - why are you adding 0 here? Why not add the offset that you want to add?

Comment: You must either know the offset while defining the dictionary, or loop over all elements of the dictionary and add the offset to each of them. Dictionaries do not implement addition with integers as "add this integer to each of the dict's values"

Comment: @kaya3 Yep, thats a good point. It was already there, I just had to replace it with a variable haha. Thank you!